How to architect a persistence structure to my android app?
I am trying to sketch an overall idea of how to structure the storage/fetching of live data from the internet to my Android app.
I will use a chart library for Jetpack Compose called Vico.
It can take and draws out data points.
I need to fetch data from public API's for the stock market, such as MarketShare which is a free REST API with JSON format.
The apps main functionality isn't set in stone, but for simplicity:
The user opens the app. It displays the graph. The graph is empty when the market is closed.
The graph draws new data continuously.
At the end of the day, the graph is cleared once again. Lets say, a candlestick chart.
But if the user completely closes the app, and reopens, the data that was already there is redrawn.
And two users using the app at different times of the day, will see the exact same graph. As the user is in the app, it keeps recomposing the chart as new data enters (lets say once every 5 seconds)
Why I don't think Room is the solution: as I understand, Room is database abstraction over SQLite for local storage on Android. But, using local storage, different users would see different graphs. For example, if user1 opens app at 3pm, but the market has been open for 5 hours already, they won't see the first 5 hours of data that should be plotted.
This leads me to think I need some "server" that fetches the data from the REST API and stores it in a database. I think the server needs to be on the cloud so that it can fetch data 24/7. Then, the application simply fetches data from the servers database, on startup (redraw old data), and every 5 seconds (draw new data)? And thus different users will be able to see the same graph, at different times of the day, and the graph will update as long as the user has a connection to the web server?
Does Firebase solve this problem or do I need to implement some other technologies? Can you refer to some technologies that together solve this problem?
